# MaskedInput control not working when using: type="number" and a mask simultaneosly

Tags: javascript, html, regex, reactjs

I have a very basic `React` code, where I use the following `Node` packages:

```
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';
```

**My problem is** that I cannot apply `type="number"` and `mask={...}` at the same time.

I want to use a masked input and at the same time pull the numeric keyboard up when the user focuses the input. That's why I want to use: `type="number"`.

My goal, is let the user introduce a numeric value with numeric keyboard and seeing a numeric mask at the same time.

Below you have a working code which you also can find and play with on:

https://codesandbox.io/s/l42v92xml

```
import React from "react";
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

export default class DollarAmount extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaskedInput
        type="text"
        mask={createNumberMask({ prefix: '$ ' })}
        placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The example above works because it is using: `type="text"`.

Remember, the conflict is `type="number"` and `mask={...}` at the same time.

The following code will also work:

```
import React from "react";
import MaskedInput from 'react-text-mask';
import createNumberMask from 'text-mask-addons/dist/createNumberMask';

export default class DollarAmount extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaskedInput
        type="number"
        placeholderChar={'\u2000'}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

because it doesn't have the `mask` attribute.

Any idea on how to get this work?

Thanks!